# How to store user data in window phone 8 app?

Tags: windows-phone-8

Please help me how to store user data in window phone 8 application?
I have a plan to develop an application on windows phone 8 which allow user create xml file to store their private data. The question is how to store user data on window 8.1 phone. After search solution, i know that 
+ Isolated Storage can store data but it just small data for application
+ Store data on SD card is read only.
So, is there any other way to store data?
Thank and sorry about my english skill!

Comment: Why exactly you want to use XML file and why exactly you dont want to use Isolated Storage?

Comment: use sqlite if your data is big to store in isolated storage..

Comment: I think Isolated Storage is small and use for application data ex: user name, user state...

Comment: I think Isolated Storage is perfect for what you need.

Answer (score 1):

ApplicationData (LocalFolder on WP8 or LocalFolder and RoamingFolder on WP8.1) is designed for what you are trying to do. The ApplicationSettings themselves are better for small pieces of data, but apps can save files of any size which the phone has room for in the LocalFolder.

See [Accessing app data with the Windows Runtime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh464917.aspx) on MSDN for details. While the docs target Windows Runtime apps, the ApplicationData and StorageFile API are available to Silverlight apps on Windows Phone 8 and later.

Additional Usings:

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using Windows.Storage;
using System.IO;
```

Code:

```
StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
StorageFile saveFile = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync("data.xml", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
using (var ras = await saveFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
{
    Stream stream = ras.GetOutputStreamAt(0).AsStreamForWrite();
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Book>));
    serializer.Serialize(stream, data);
}
```

If you need more structured data than XML then you can store a SQLite database in the local folder. If you need more space than is reasonable for an app to store on the device then you'll need to move it to a web service. [Azure Mobile Services](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/mobile-services/) is a good place to do that. You can call such a service from a Windows Phone Silverlight app, but the wizards will generate Universal apps.

Comment: Thank Rob. I will try this way!